# wordpress query 2 sets of meta keys

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to do a custom sql query to get 2 lots of post_meta keys and there values. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
    $title = $term->name ;
    $userid =  $current_user->user_email;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta  WHERE meta_key='user_programme_name' AND meta_value='".$title."' AND meta_key='user_email' AND meta_value='".$userid."' ");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows > 0 ) {
?> 

<p style="width:430px;">You have already requested a place on this course</p>

<?php } ?>
```

The first part of the query works when i jsut query the first set of keys and values:

```
meta_key='user_programme_name' AND meta_value='".$title."'
```

But as soon as i add the second lot:

```
AND meta_key='user_email' AND meta_value='".$userid."'
```

It doesn't work. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this :

```
$args = array(  'post_type' => 'myposttype',
            'posts_per_page' => …,
            'offset' => …,
            'meta_query'=>array(    
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key'=>'_first_key',                    
                    'value'=> youvalue,
                    'type' => 'DATE', // etc.
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'=>'_second_key',       
                                        'value'=> youvalue,
                    'type' => 'DATE', // etc.
                    'compare' => '='
                    )
            )
);
$yourloop  = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: with the above are you able to count the number of rows?

Comment: This solution is more WP friendly. :)

Comment: Yes you can count the number of rows. $yourloop->found_posts.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your SQL syntax for selecting multiple values on the same column:

```
<?php

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta  WHERE meta_key IN ('user_programme_name', 'user_email') AND meta_value IN ('.$title.', '.$userid.') ");

?>
```

Comment: just looking at this again, and it doesnt seem to be working as i thought... both values need to be looked at. i think at the moment it is detecting that the $userid is the same and not regarding the $title

Comment: I see. You would need to do a `join`.